# date comparison to check if last date has passed

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net

I have a DB table with the following columns

> 1. PolicyNumber
> 2. NextPremiumDate
> 3. PremiumNumber

### Example

For each `PolicyNumber` i have 5 `NextPremiumDates`.

I want to display the 1st NextPremiumDate which is easy ...but i want to show the next `NextPremiumDate` only after the last `NextPremiumDate` has passed...How do i check if the last date has passed??

I mean if i have 5 dates in the table given above...how do i check if the 1st date has passed then show 2nd date ...if 2nd has passed show 3rd and so on.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Top 1 NextPremiumDate 
FROM MyTable
where NextPremiumDate >= getdate() 
ORDER BY NextPremiumDate ASC
```

Comment: unless I botched your structure, it would be something like that

Comment: `SELECT MIN(NextPremiumDate) 
FROM MyTable
where NextPremiumDate >= getdate() ` :)

Comment: That assumes that there is only one NextPremiumDate column, but it sounded to me like there were a fixed number of Premium Dates, implying there were 5 separate columns.  Is that true?